# How to replace variable with values in another file

Tags: php

I am trying to replace values of variable

I have following file

**demo.html**

```
<h1>{$heading}</h1>
<p>{$paragraph}</p>
```

**demo.php**

```
    $html = file_get_contents('email.html', true);
    eval($html);
```

here I am trying to include that file and replace values of `$heading` and `$paragraph` and than echo.

my question is how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `eval()` is not needed for this code, as it contains no PHP which needs to be executed. `eval()` is a **very dangerous** function.
You contents is in `$html` as a string, therefore, you can now use a significantly safer function called [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) to look for, and replace the value placeholders with the correct data.

The function uses the following arguments: `str_replace($search, $replace, $subject)`, accepts arrays as arguments, and returns the full string with replaced values.

Therefore, to answer your question:

```
// $html = ...

$search = array(
    '{$heading}',
    '{$paragraph}'
);
$replace = array(
    'My Heading',
    'My Paragraph',
);

$replaced_string = str_replace($search, $replace, $html)
```

Comment: **very dangerous** because it sounds like **evil** ? And the variables in the code can be **evaluated** if its done right ;) But like **goto** everybody avoid to use it. PHP is **dangerous** at all if you are not using it with save coded conditions.

Comment: Absolutely. For a trivial task however, using eval is dangerous because it opens up exploits that an inexperienced developer might not know about. While it could be `eval()`'d, there is an alternative option which does the same thing, and is a lot safer :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

```
$replace = array(
  '{$heading}'   => 'Replaced heading',
  '{$paragraph}' => 'Replaced paragraph'
);

$html = file_get_contents('email.html', true);
$html = str_reaplce(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $html);
echo $html;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change **demo.html** to **demo.tpl.php**

In **demo.php** just do:

```
 $heading = 'Heading';
 $paragraph = 'Para';
 include 'demo.tpl.php';
```

That should work.

OR if no name change is possible, in **demo.php** do:

```
$heading = 'Heading';
$paragraph = 'Para';
print str_replace(
          array('{$heading}','{$paragraph}'), # use '  not " here!!!
          array($heading,$paragraph),
          file_get_contents('demo.html'));
```

Should work too.